# Need to get words at "even" indices from string

Tags: python, slice

Here is a string as an example.

```
s = 'asdf df d f d ssa'.
```

I need to get words at even indices from a string. For the above string `s`, the words are:

```
1. 'asdf'
2. 'df'   // Even index
3. 'd'
4. 'f'    // Even index
5. 'd'
6. 'ssa'  // Even index
```

A correct output would be
`'df f ssa'`. I think I would do this with a slice.

How might I go about this?

Comment: what do you mean by even chars?

Comment: We're not going to do your homework for you. If you have some code that you've written that you're having an issue with, and you've read [help] and [mcve], feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: Please rewrite your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Check out [Explain Python's Slice Notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation.)

Comment: Honestly, looking at the example, I still don't know what the OP is asking. Maybe this is actually a unique request, and we just need a few more examples to understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You meant words at *even* indices (if that sounds correct). `split` and then *slice* with a step of 2 starting at 1:

```
>>> ' '.join(s.split()[1::2])
'df f ssa'
```

Your *even* would mean *odd* here, since indexing starts from zero.